# Remove space from numbers - Leave rest intact

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

Full disclosure: I'm no programmer (which will probably be evident in a second). I frequently copy numbers from one sheet to another and numbers bigger than 999 have a space between the first and the second number. I have tried to make script (with help from similar scripts I've found here) that remove these spaces at the click of a button but it only kinda works.

Here's a sample sheet with my code included: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11_CWZfhBupUpBKYi7I9cwGBakSr4LikOm0bGft6YA7Q/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried my best to modify the Regex-expression to do what I want but I guess my knowledge is just too poor.

```
....
function Remove_space() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Input");

  var r = sheet.getRange("E4:E50");
  var v = r.getValues();

  for(var k=0;k<v.length;k++)
    for(var j=0;j<v[0].length;j++)
      v[k][j]=v[k][j].toString().replace(/\s/g, "");
  r.setValues(v);
};
....
```

Can anyone help me out and make the spaces go away but leave my commas intact?

It does remove the spaces but for some reason it also converts my commas (decimal separator) into periods. If there are no decimals it's no problem.

Comment: Just tried this and all it is doing is removing the spaces, looks fine to me. Are you running this function as part of a larger script by any chance?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code posted is all there is. Maybe it could be you have a different locale than me that makes it work regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

- ***String conversion:*** Javascript doesn't support `,` as decimal separator. So, when you getValue(),  they're automatically converted to `.`. When you `setValue()`,  it'll be converted back to `,`. But during  the execution of the function, you use `.toString()`, which makes the period `.` permanent.

#### Solution:

- ***Get as String type:*** Use `getDisplayValues()` if you want to get numbers as  strings with `,` as decimal separator intact. OR
- ***Set as Number type:*** Convert the regex replaced string back to a number. You should also manually convert comma `,` to period `.` in this case to cast it back to number type.

#### Snippet:

```
 r.getDisplayValues();
```

OR

```
v[k][j]=Number(v[k][j].toString().replace(/\s/g, "").replace(/\,/g,"."));
```

#### References:

- [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)
- [Range#getDisplayValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues): Notice that it returns `String []`, whereas `getValues()` returns `Object []`

Comment: Thank you very much for shedding some light. The DisplayValues did the trick.